# How to run the trained tflite model in single image in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow, pose-estimation, tflite

I have a trained tflite model, which has only 11 key points and I need to detect the same key points in my android code. I have downloaded the tflite sample code and modify some part to display the key points in single Image. And my trained model has an input size of 640 * 640, my model input size after upload in netron and arrived input size is 1,640,640,3 and the output size is 1,38,8400. Can anyone share me the sample code of how to display the key points from the trained model. Your help will be highly appreciated. Please help me on this.

Comment: What architecture is the model ? Also did you visualized the keypoints in python while you trained the model ?